# oracle service bus how to transform message and insert current datetime in osb

Tags: xslt, xquery, osb, oracle-service-bus

i have a message. While proxy service request, i want insert current datetime to message.How can do it?.Please help me.I am using xslt transform but osb do not support xslt 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OSB supports xquery functions that can be used in the proxy service. if you want to insert the current date & time in to the message (i suppose it is an XML), then use the insert node, and the xquery function **current-dateTime()** which will generate the system Date into the tag that you specify in your xpath

Regards,
Balaji